# Do I need an ESTA if entering the US from Canada by train

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, esta, uk-citizens

As a UK citizen, I will be flying to Vancouver (for which I will need an eTA) and then taking an AMTRAK train to Seattle. I will stay in Seattle for several days before returning to Vancouver and flying back to the UK. Do I need an ESTA for entering the US during this trip?

Comment: Dear Rich, did you do the trip? Can you please tell me, I am doing the same thing, how does it go? Where do you do the CBP check? Before boarding the train? Or you have to step off the train at the border and do the biometrics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Not having an ESTA will involve you in a lengthy secondary process to get a paper I-94.**

While [US Customs and Border Patrol says](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094/~/do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta%3F):

> If you are [a citizen of a VWP country and] coming by land, you do not need to have ESTA authorization, however, you should return your green I-94W card upon departure.

on closer investigation it turns out that [US CBP does not consider an international train to be a land crossing](http://www.amtrakcascades.com/riders-guide?anchor=1) (presumably there is some confusion about how trains actually work).

> Travelers crossing from Canada into the U.S. on Amtrak Cascades trains AND are NOT U.S. or Canadian citizens nor have a valid visa, MUST have an approved ESTA, otherwise a paper form CBP I-94 will be required. If you are a VWP (Visa Waiver Program) traveler, this applies to you. (Amtrak Cascades trains do not fall under the U.S. CBP “Land Border Crossing” definition.)

Tom W's excellent answer gives more details.

Comment: Quite unusual! So if I come by land and am leaving by sea, I need to have contact with an airline?

Comment: @AndrejaKo Who says that people writing the CBP site can talk Inglish.

Comment: @Karlson Well, you know, I would have sort of assumed that, but you can never know!

Comment: @DJClayworth: An example of  "if you are arriving by land and departing by land or sea" would be someone driving from Toronto to Buffalo and back. And you say everybody talks to an airline rep once during the boarding process. Pretty sure there is no airline and no boarding process involved in that drive ;-) So I don't think you're talking about the situation that sentence describes. You're probably talking about the situation it *intended* to describe, but somebody at the CBP website has typed the wrong thing or whatever.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: the point is that you need to return your I-94W. Airlines are authorized to take them from you. The point is that when lesving you don't interact with CBP, but someone has to take your I-94W.

Comment: I believe the I-94W is also cheaper than an ESTA (yep, the form ain't free!) but only good for one visit.

Comment: By first-hand experience I can tell you this answer is **wrong**. U.S. Customs and Border Patrol do not consider trains to be "land". I and a group of four friends were fiercely chastised by the Border Patrol agents at Vancouver Pacific Central for not having completed ESTAs.

Comment: The CBP has now corrected the confusing language at your link.  It now reads, "If you are arriving by land and departing by **air**, you should return your green I-94W to the airline representative prior to boarding your flight."

Answer (score 14):

**Yes.**.

The accepted answer correctly quotes the U.S. Customs and Border Patrol advice, however nowhere in this advice does it point out that CBP **does not consider trains to be land**. What they actually mean is arriving by **road**.

I know this from first-hand experience having departed for the U.S. by Amtrak starting in Vancouver. There I was firmly chastised for not having completed an ESTA. Only when one of my friends questioned this was it understood that we had followed the instructions as we understood them, but our understanding was wrong.

The [Amtrak website](http://www.amtrakcascades.com/riders-guide?anchor=1) claims:

> Amtrak Cascades trains do not fall under the U.S. CBP “Land Border Crossing” definition.
>
> Travelers crossing from Canada into the U.S. on Amtrak Cascades trains AND are NOT U.S. or Canadian citizens nor have a valid visa, MUST have an approved ESTA, otherwise a paper form CBP I-94 will be required.

Getting a paper form I-94 is possible but it means delays at best, according to the [CBP](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/i-94-instructions):

> If a traveler would like a paper Form I-94, one can be requested during the inspection process. All requests will be accommodated in a secondary setting.

Comment: It is difficult to find an official source for this surprising answer but http://britishexpats.com/forum/maple-leaf-98/amtrak-cascades-van-seattle-803915/#post10817974 corroborates. "Re: Amtrak Cascades Van - Seattle Hubby went on it recently - they did US immi at Van , , they asked if he had an ESTA" and "Yep, we went last summer and they asked me for an ESTA too."

Comment: @chx Quite. The only even remotely authoritative source I can find is the [Amtrak website](http://www.amtrakcascades.com/riders-guide?anchor=1): *"Travelers crossing from Canada into the U.S. on Amtrak Cascades trains AND are NOT U.S. or Canadian citizens nor have a valid visa, MUST have an approved ESTA, otherwise a paper form CBP I-94 will be required."*

Comment: Furthermore: *"Amtrak Cascades trains do not fall under the U.S. CBP “Land Border Crossing” definition."*

Comment: If there was an edit to this answer to provide a link to the fact about trains not being a land border, I would delete my accepted answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth I have done so.

Comment: Bother. I forgot I can't delete an accepted answer.

Comment: Dear Tom, I am planning to do the same thing, going from Canada to US with amtrac in Vancouver. I have approved ESTA. Can you please tell me where CBP will check me? Before boarding the train? Or on the train? Or do I have to step off the train at the border?

Comment: There is a checkpoint between the ticket hall and the platform. I believe they scan your passport and ask a couple of questions if you don't need an I-94. I did need an I-94 so the process took slightly longer. Additionally, customs agents board the train and collect your customs declaration slips and check passports at the physical border.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need it, but when using the Train from Vancouver (though not the one from Montreal), it will exempt you from having to obtain a green I-94W form.

Comment: Filling out a paper I-94W and paying for it there and then was our solution, but this attracted some strong criticism from the CBP officers present, as this is not how you're *supposed* to declare eligibility under the VWP. You're *supposed* to use the ESTA to do this, prior to travel, although it is not an absolute requirement.

Comment: @TomW If you're not supposed to, then why does that form exist in the first place?

Comment: Don't ask me, ask CBP. [This web page](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/form-i-94/) implies that it's something of a legacy process. Maybe they keep the paper forms around because travellers keep inexplicably turning up without ESTAs...

Comment: @TomW I recall seeing a proposed regulation to extend ESTA to all VWP travelers (that is, to start requiring it of land and sea travelers), but until that is implemented, I suspect that the officers' criticism was the result either of misunderstanding or of irritation that they had to do more paperwork than they otherwise would have.

Comment: That's because you're clearing customs in Vancouver, and not at the physical border crossing. The train makes no stops between Vancouver and Bellingham, apart from a short stop at the rail siding in Blaine, WA ( I think it still does this ) so dogs can get on and check for contraband, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Amtrak website makes too much of a deal from the requirement to have a paper I-94 form...

First of all technically there is no longer such a thing as a "paper" I-94 - all entry records have been fully electronic since 2015. The paper that's stapled into your passport when you cross the border has no more legal weight than a print out from the DHS website stating your current I-94 status.

Second, all visa holders (non-VWP eligible) need a "paper" I-94 as well if they don't have a valid one when they cross the border. Therefore all class A border crossings (which includes the train station) are well equipped for issuing one, so it's not a big deal. Just because the CBP officer is lazy doesn't mean he's right for chastising you.

Finally, I'm not sure why Amtrak claims rail crossings are not "land" crossings. If it was truly so VWP-eligible passport holders would not be allowed to board the train without an ESTA rather than offered the option of getting an I-94W on the spot. So I think there's some amount of confusion over how the VWP works on their side.

Comment: "there is no longer such a thing as a "paper" I-94": USCIS still issues paper I-94s when people change status in the US.  These records are not integrated with CBP's online I-94 database.  I don't know whether there are plans to do so.

Comment: Amtrak trains on the Cascades are a bit different than road crossings in that you actually clear customs in Vancouver, and not the first point of crossing. From Vancouver to the USA there are no stops. You're on Canadian soil and have legally entered the USA. Similar to transborder terminals at Canadian airports that have secured terminals only for US departures. I believe the train still stops in Blaine to do a check for drugs, etc. but there's no customs done there. All passengers are considered cleared in Vancouver by US CBP officers in Pacific Central Station in Vancouver.