# Crossing rainbow bridge by foot from Canadian side to US side without a visa

Tags: visas, land-borders, german-citizens, niagara-falls

In October I will be going from Europe (Germany) to Canada and then continuing to Buffalo before flying to Miami. I will leave my rental car at the Canadian side of Niagara Falls and cross the rainbow bridge in the evening by foot.

I will not have a visa because ESTA only applies for boat/airplane travels.
Will they care if I just get there with my luggage and without a car and apply directly for a visa or is it a normal procedure? Can I prepare something (visa application etc.)?

Comment: What's your citizenship ? Are you sure you even need a visa ?

Comment: German... I can apply for the ESTA program which is really easy but they say it`s only for arrival at a shipport / airport

Comment: ESTA ≠ VWP, you don't need an ESTA. You can just show up at the border

Comment: Thx a lot.. was confused by Waiver and ESTA. So I´ll just show up there fill out that I94W and hope for the best... thx for the link!

Comment: Even if you had ESTA, you would not have a visa, because ESTA is not a visa. You will be using the visa waiver program, so you will not get a visa at the border, either.  There week be some paperwork, though, and some stamps. I think the cost is $6.

Comment: @phoog? $6? As a UK national, with a UK passport, I crossed the Rainbow Bridge and filled out I94W in 2013(ish). No cost involved in the paperwork. There was a 50c cost to use the bridge though.

Comment: So I do not need a visa to enter the us? Oh my, that`s what waiver means.. alright thought is was something like wave'ing.. thx a lot.. will do the paperwork and bring dollars for the payment..

Comment: @AndyT did you have a valid ESTA? My understanding is that they only charge the $6 if you don't. But I'm a US citizen and the only person I've ever crossed the land border with has a visa, so this is all second-hand information.

Comment: @phoog - No, I didn't have a valid ESTA. You can read a (related) story on that at my question [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61892/if-i-enter-the-us-by-land-not-needing-esta-would-i-then-need-esta-to-enter-by/). But looking at the comments there you read it at the time of posting anyway.